# Why does getDocumentFilter need to cast to AbstractDocument?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextpane

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package texteditor;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class TextPad implements DocumentListener,ChangeListener{
    private JTextPane textArea;
    private Document textDoc;

    private int selectionOffset;
    private int selectionLength;

    public void init()
    {
        //System.out.println("Constructor invoked");
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Text Editor");
        //JMenuBar menuBar = window.getJMenuBar();

        /**
        //Create menu bar
        JMenuBar menuBar= new JMenuBar();
        //File Menu
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Save"));
        * */

       // menuBar.add(fileMenu);
       //window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        this.textArea= new JTextPane();

        this.textDoc = this.textArea.getDocument();
        this.textDoc.addDocumentListener(this);
        this.textArea.getCaret().addChangeListener(this);
        //System.out.println(d.getClass());

        //override  default text generation ****THIS LINE******
       ((AbstractDocument)this.textDoc).getDocumentFilter();

        //Add scorllable interface in jtextpane
        window.add(new JScrollPane(this.textArea));

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
       //System.out.println("changed");

    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
          System.out.println("removed");
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {

        try
        {
          System.out.println(this.textDoc.getText(0,this.textDoc.getLength()));

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }

    }
    /**
     *
     * @param e
     */
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println(this.textArea.getCaret().getMark());
    }

}
```

Why does casting to `abstractDocument` as `((AbstractDocument)this.textDoc).getDocumentFilter();` works but without casting it like
`this.textDoc.getDocumentFilter();` does throw error of cant find the method. can anyone please explain?

**EDIT:**

```
if(this.textDoc instanceof AbstractDocument)
        {
            System.out.println("Yes it is");
        }
```

prints `Yes it is` which is also implies it is kind of `AbstractDocument`. I dont' understand then why calling method of `AbstractDocument` throws error.

Comment: Because `getDocumentFilter` is not declared in the `Document` interface, but the `AbstractDocument` class...yes, mind boggling I know, but that's the way it is...

Comment: testDoc is a PlainDocument object but is declared as a Document interface type, and to get the methods of PlainDocument or its parent AbstractDocument, you must cast.

Comment: I dont understand then why ` if(this.textDoc instanceof AbstractDocument)
        {
            System.out.println("Yes it is");
        }` prints 'yes it is' 

as it implies textDoc is also kind of AbstractDocument, then why method of it show that error?

Comment: I have been edited the OP. please check it.

Comment: You are confusing variable type with object type. They are two different things.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels please elaborate

Comment: The type of variable returned by the getXxx method is Document but that doesn't prevent the method from returning a more specific type of Document, here a PlainDocument,and that's the object's type.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, but using this.textDoc.toString() returning `DefaultStyledDocument` not `PlainDocument`.

Answer (score 2):

HoverCraft has it right. With Java, you can only access the methods and properties of the object according to how it is cast. So, to demonstrate

```
public interface Fooer {
    public int doFoo();
}

public class Foo implements Fooer{
    public int doFoo(){return 0;}
    public void doNoFooer(){}
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    public void doYesFooer(){}
}
```

Here is what would happen if you used those definitions:

```
Foo foo = new Bar();
foo.doNoFooer(); // fine because it is a method of Foo
foo.doFoo();
foo.doYesFooer(); // causes an error because the variable is improperly typed.

Fooer fooer = foo;
fooer.doFoo(); // find because it is part of the definition of Fooer
fooer.doYesFoo(); // causes an error because the variable is improperly typed.
fooer.doNoFoo(); // causes an error because the variable is improperly typed.

Bar bar = (Bar) foo;
// notice that the next three do not cause errors.
bar.doYesFooer();
bar.doNoFooer();
bar.doFoo();
```

Comment: yes, but subclass will have the parent class method inheritly. According to manual `defaultStyledDocument` inherits from `abstractDocument` including the method `getDocmentFilter().
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultStyledDocument.html
And this.textDoc is of class `defaultStyledDocument` (if i use this.textDoc.toString(); it prints `defaultStyledDocument`. So According to this method getDocumentFilter() should be avialble. is not it?

Comment: But it is typed as a Document. It does not matter what a variable actually contains, you can only use it according to its type.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the previous answer by cwallenpoole and to give a reason as to *why* Java works this way, consider the following snippet of code

```
class Foo {
  int doFoo() {return 0;}
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  int doBar() {return 1;}
}

class FooBar {
  static int useBar(Foo foo) {
    ((Bar) foo).doBar();
  }
}

Bar someBar = new Bar();
Foo someFoo = new Foo();
FooBar.useBar(someBar) // compiles, no runtime error
FooBar.useBar(someFoo) // compiles, runtime error
```

Java's type system is meant to make the second invocation a compile time error, rather than a potentially hard to debug runtime error. Clearly, in this example it would not be difficult to debug, or possibly add an instanceof check. However, using casts defeats the type system, and additionally defeats any compile-time safety a type system provides to the programmer, which is one of the major reasons for using a statically typed language in the first place.

To be explicit, the following is a compile-time error, warning the programmer that based on the type of the variable, the variable does not necessarily have that function, even if a subclass defines it.

```
class FooBar {
  static int useBar(Foo foo) {
    foo.doBar();
  }
}
```